# How much liquidity is needed to introduce new ERC20 on uniswap?

Tags: erc-20, contract-deployment, exchanges, liquidity-provider

How much liquidity is needed to introduce a new ERC20 on uniswap?

For example for 250 billion tokens of new ERC20 contract "X" how much it would cost to create a pool so the 1 "X" Token value would be approx 0.01 or less. Or maybe it's recommended to provide a smaller pool for the first exchange pool?

So far I did create an example pool for 5000 "X" Tokens, it cost me like $40, but to publish the pool they asked for 1.8K USD. Is there a chance I will get this money back or it's the price for adding a new token for the first time?

And as far as I understand for new tokens, when you create a pool for the first time it costs a lot more than after. Why it's like that?

And last but not least, if I will create a liquidity pool for the new token "x" for:

**5000** "X" Tokens + **0.2ETH** (801.151956 USD), means the 1 "X" Token price will be approx:

**0.16** cents per "X" Token. If someone buys 1 "X" Token, i will get 0.16cents + 3.6%?

Answer (score 1):

The more you put into LP, the more stable your currency price will be. There are no minimal requirements for sum of tokens.

When you create LP, you pay for gas, to deploy the new contract once. You don't need to pay additional fees later, except trading fee for every swap.

The price inside pool grows and shrinks based on amount of tokens inside. Pool with 5000 X and 0.2 ETH after first swap for 1 X token became 4999 X and 0.2 ETH + "0,16 CENTS" (in ETH). So the price of X will rise because of it.